# How $ \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_5 \approx \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_5$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism, direct-product

In the book **Contemporary abstract algebra** by **Joseph Gallian** in page 166 the following things are said :

> By using results above in an iterative fashion, one can express the same group (up to isomorphism) in many different forms. For example, we have
> $$ \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_5 \approx \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_5 \approx \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_{30} \\(*) $$

> Similarly,
> $$ \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_5 
> \approx 
> \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_5 \approx 
> \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_3 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_5
> \approx
>  \mathbb {Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb {Z}_{10}\\ (**)$$
> Thus, $ \mathbb {Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{30} \approx \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{10} $

I am not understanding how they are talking about the isomorphisms between these product groups with the help of the results above. I have tried a lot but can't get through it. Please help. It's really important in my self study.

The results above were :

> **Theorem 8.2** Let G and H be finite cyclic groups. Then $G \oplus H$ is cyclic if and only if $|G|$ and $|H|$ are relatively prime.

> **Corollary 1** An external direct product $G_1 \oplus G_2 \oplus ... \oplus G_n$ of a finite number of finite cyclic groups is cyclic iff $|G_i|$ and $|G_j|$ are relatively prime when $i \ne j$.

> **Corollary 2** Let $ m = n_1n_2 ...n_k $. Then $\mathbb Z_m$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{n_1} \oplus \mathbb Z_{n_2} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb Z_{n_k}$ iff $n_i$ and $n_j$ are relatively prime when $i \ne j$.

Comment: Can you see why $\Bbb Z_2\oplus\Bbb Z_3\cong\Bbb Z_6$?

Comment: Yes I do and infact I can see the use of Corollary 2 to prove it too.

Comment: In Corollary 2, it should say "isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{n_1} \oplus \mathbb Z_{n_2} \oplus ... \oplus \mathbb Z_{n_k}$", and that is precisely the result invoked in $(*)$ and $(**)$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I corrected the typo.... I'm just not getting how am I using these corollaries to to say that the result (*) and (**) are true. I thought of $Z_6$ being isomorphic to $Z_2 \oplus Z_3$ and then replacing it in place of $Z_6$...but is it how it's done? Doesn't doing so change the structure of the groups?

Comment: @runway44 in case you didn't understand, I still don't know how any of these corollaries helping to prove the examples, I've added another comment, please see that too and help me

Comment: @Pritam two groups that are isomorphic have the same structure. If $G \approxeq (A \oplus B)$ then $A \oplus B \oplus N = (A \oplus B) \oplus N \approxeq G \oplus N$

Comment: I think I see it now, as $Z_2 \oplus Z_3 \approx Z_6$ so it is replaced by $Z_6$ and again as $Z_5 \oplus Z_6 \approx Z_{30}$ that's why it is replaced by $Z_{30}$.

Answer (score 2):

I think I see it now, as $Z_2 \oplus Z_3 \approx Z_6$ so it is replaced by $Z_6$ and again as $Z_5 \oplus Z_6 \approx Z_{30}$ that's why it is replaced by $Z_{30}$ and doing so on in the next cases too.

Comment: Please accept this answer, so the question is marked as "answered".